# Eclipse : how to insert content assist proposals?

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, content-assist

Just a little annoyance :

### Context :

The content assist is set up and work most of the time.
But I just tried to write document.getElementById;

### Problem :

The problem is I cannot select one of the proposals for document.get: when I select an entry,the popup disappears and nothing is inserted in text.

I noticed that it is preceded by a green dot. Other proposals with a blue triangle are inserted normally.

Any hint why I cannot make it work ?

Thanks,

### UPDATE :

Eclipse 3.8 debian

Comment: What OS and version of Eclipse are you running?

Answer (score 1):

It sorts out that the culprit was the option "guess filled functions argument". It messed up everything. Now I'm back to work (as expected).

This feature is disabled by default, but if, like me, you  set it up and forgot about it, here is how to disable it :

Windows -> Javascript -> Editor -> content assist -> guess filled function argument

It should be disabled.

Comment: can you explain the steps you took to disable that option for future devs with the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've found that on sometimes the assist pop-ups can be finicky. Pop-ups can be in either selected or unselected states. If the pop-up is in an unselected state clicking the actions sometimes does not either work or the option can be incomplete.
Try testing and making sure that the pop-up is selected before you choose an option. (The pop-up border should change and you may get a scroll bar to indicate the difference.

Comment: It is selected. I do the exact same thing as selecting the blue triangle values...

Comment: I don't use Eclipse for Javacript and so don't know the notation your speaking of. What are the differences between the two options that  the icons are indicating?

Comment: The green circle is for public methods and blue triangle is for default (package visible) method.

Comment: Have you tried a clean install of Eclipse to see if it is reproducible? (You don't have to uninstall your current version)

Comment: Tried with 4.3, same thing.. will open a ticket!

Comment: That would have been my next suggestion! Post a link to the ticket in your original question once you make it.

Comment: Interesting : the culprit was the option "guess filled functions argument". Desactivated it and everything works as wonders. Will answer my question.